# How to get the value of text box from one component to other and vice versa in angular 8

Tags: angular, typescript

I have 2 component login and home. I want to capture the value of text box from login component  and pass into the text box of home component onclick of proceed button of login component. similarly I want to capture the value of text box from home component and pass into the text box of login component again onclick of proceed button of home component. Here is the code below

### login.component.html

```
<div>
<p>Parent Component</p>
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="inptext">
</div><br>
<button (click)="proceed()">Proceed</button>
```

### login.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router'; 
@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
  users:any;
  constructor(private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit() {
 
  }
 proceed(){
     alert(this.inptext);
     this.router.navigateByUrl('/home');
 }
  
}
```

### home.component.html

```
<div>
<p>Child Component</p>
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="inptext">
</div><br>
<button (click)="proceed()">Proceed</button>
```

### home.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router'; 
@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  getListData: boolean = false;
  constructor(private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit() {

  }
 proceed(){
      
      alert(this.inptext);
       this.router.navigateByUrl('/');
 }
}
```

Comment: https://angular.io/tutorial

Answer (score 0):

1. first you need to import home.component in app.module.ts and declare it inside the providers section
2. then import the home.component in the login.component in the login component then inject the component in the constructor `public home: HomeComponent`
3. then you can access all the variables and functiones inside the homeComponent like `this.home.variable_name`

This way you can assign the value of input to the variable of home component inside the function which cals in onCLick method

Answer (score 0):

You can do it easily by using @input & shared service.

//to-login-service.ts

```
@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})
export class ToLoginService {
  private data: Subject<string> = new Subject<string>();

  sent(val: string) {
    this.data.next(val);
  }

  get(): Observable<string> {
    return this.data.asObservable();
  }
}
```

//login-component.ts

```
@Component({
selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
  inptext: string;
  passtoHome: string;
  getFromHome: string;

  constructor(private toLoginService: ToLoginService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.toLoginService.get().subscribe(val => {
      this.getFromHome = val;
    });
  }

  proceed() {
    this.passtoHome = this.inptext;
  }
}
```

//login-component.html

```
<h2>Sent From Home(Child): {{getFromHome}}</h2>

<div>
  <p>Parent Component</p>
  <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="inptext">
</div><br>
<button (click)="proceed()">Proceed</button>


<hr/>

<app-home [pass-from-login]="passtoHome"></app-home>
```

//home-component.ts

```
@Component({
selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  inptext: string;
  sentFromLogin: string;

  @Input('pass-from-login')
  set passFromLogin(val: string) {
    this.sentFromLogin = val;
  }

  constructor(private toLoginService: ToLoginService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  proceed() {
    this.toLoginService.sent(this.inptext);
  }
}
```

//home-component.html

```
<h2>Sent From Login (Parent): {{sentFromLogin}}</h2>
<div>
  <p>Child Component</p>
  <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="inptext">
</div><br>
<button (click)="proceed()">Proceed</button>
```

Now you can find the view like this:

[image]

Comment: Using input you can pass value to child component.    And using output you can call a parent components function from child component.

Comment: Can you please tell me how to use in this code, Can you please create a demo

Comment: I've edited my post with your example, wish it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to using `Component interaction` which have some standard ways:

1. Using `@output`, `@Input` decorators for parent and child communications.
2. Using `Shared Service`
3. Using `Observable` to emit events
4. Using `State Managements` such as `ngrx`

For more information visit [Component interaction](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction)

Different ways from #1 to #4 are depend on different parameters such as your `Application Scope`, `State Management Policy` and So on.

Here you can simply define a `Shared Service` which is injected in both component and have
two `Setter` & `Getter` method for keeping your desired value.

See this example:

**shared.model.ts**

```js
export interface IItem {
    name: string;
}
```

**shared.service.ts**

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { IItem } from '../entities/iItem';
 
@Injectable()
export class ModelService {
 
    private _items:IItem[] = [];
 
    addItem(item: IItem) {
        this._items.push(item);
    }
 
    getItems(): IItem[] {
        return this._items;
    }
}
```

**Component.template.html**

```html
<div>
  <input [(ngModel)]="item.name" placeholder="Item name here..">
  <button (click)="addItem()">Add Item</button>
</div>
```

**Component.component.ts**

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ModelService } from '../services/model.service';
import { IItem } from '../entities/iItem';
 
@Component({
  selector: 'create-item',
  templateUrl: './createitem.component.html'
})
export class CreateItemComponent {
 
  private _item:IItem = {name:'',description:'',price:0};
 
  constructor(private _modelService: ModelService){}
 
  public get Item():IItem{
     return this._item;
  }
 
  public addItem(){
     const currentItem:IItem = {
         name:this._item.name,
         description:this._item.description,
         price:this._item.price
     };
 
    this._modelService.addItem(currentItem);
  }
}
```

**ViewComponent.template.html**

```html
<div>
  <button (click)="printItems()">Print Item</button>
</div>
```

**ViewComponent.component.ts**

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ModelService } from '../services/model.service';
 
@Component({
  selector: 'view-items',
  templateUrl: './viewitems.component.html'
})
 
export class ViewItemsComponent {
 
constructor(private _modelService: ModelService){}
 
 public printItems(){
    console.log('items in warehouse:');
    console.log(this._modelService.getItems());
 }
 
}
```

For more information and explanation visit this [link](https://developerslogblog.wordpress.com/2019/04/23/how-to-use-angular-services-to-share-data-between-components/).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but here scenario is different, onclick of button need to capture the textbox value of one component to other and vice versa

Comment: So use `Observable` to emit an event. and in `Subscribe()` in the other component bind it to the other textvalue

Comment: we can do with input and output ,but I am not getting how to do

Comment: your component aren't parent - child based on your code